# How to change ${USER} variable in IntelliJ IDEA without changing OS user name?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

By `${USER}` Intellij idea [means](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) the login name of the current user. But what if login differ from name used as developer name? Is it possible to set `USER` to other value without changing OS login name?

Comment: *Probably* not.  I don't think I've seen it any different than the name of the user that was logged in.

Comment: You can hard code it in the template.

Comment: `USER` is an environment variable set by your operating system / shell (assuming you're on a POSIX system). I think you'll run into all kinds of trouble if you set it to a “wrong” value.  But if you insist, try starting the application via `env USER="whatever" intellij-idea` or how that binary is called.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can modify the file **idea.exe.vmoptions** or **idea64.exe.vmoptions**, which should be in the bin folder of your IDE installation. For linux version, it could be **idea.vmoptions**. You need to add there a parameter:

```
-Duser.name=YOURNAME
```

#### How to open the file:

- `Ctrl+Shift+A` > type "vm options" > select option
- Help > Edit custom VM options...

This would make your `${USER}` variable inside IntelliJ Idea equals to parameter value and you don't have to change the current OS user login name. I've just tested it in the IntelliJ Idea 14.1.3 with file and code templates.

Comment: I confirm for IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 in Linux. I added the following line in *~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/idea64.vmoptions*:

`-Duser.name=Firstname Lastname`

Comment: Mac file location: /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions . Unless you put the application on different folder.

Comment: You can actually do this from inside intelliJ. This link describes it for android studio http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration. Probably IDEA has the same

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to *Restart* the IDE after making the above change!

Comment: I confirm for Android Studio 2.2.2 in Windows by @KlitosG. provided link using `-Duser.name=YOURNAME` syntax.

Comment: To avoid re-adding the line when I install a new version of Intellij IDEA, I added the line to `idea.exe.vmoptions` in the `.IntelliJIdea2016.3` folder of my home directory, instead of in the `bin` folder.

Comment: It does not work for my macOS Sierra of IntelliJ Idea 2016.3

Comment: I confirm this works for IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 in Windows.
File is: JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions

Answer (score 27):

To change the ${USER} variable for just the current user (rather than system wide) select Help->Edit Custom VM Options and add the following to the file that opens in your editor:

```
-Duser.name=USER
```

Then save the file and restart your editor.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Answer (score 0):

For intellij 2021 the config is in this directory on linux

/home/xxxx/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/

Find this file

idea64.vmoptions

Add the line:

-Duser.name=XXX XXXX

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mention that (at least on Windows, 10 ENTERPRISE) the file idea64.exe.vmoptions needs each option on its own line. I have spent some time unsuccessfully trying a line like:

```
-Xmx8192m -Duser.name=John Doe
```

It must be on separate lines:

```
-Xmx8192m
-Duser.name=John Doe
```

The file location on my machine was:

```
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\idea64.exe.vmoptions
```